# how to add random spikes to signal in python

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to add some random spikes and make a time series signal polluted?
I need a random signal with normal distribution and I am using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, uniform

x = np.random.randn(20000)
y =  = np.random.randn(20000)
```

and want to add some random spikes to the signal. desired time series should be something like this:
[image]
I have tried this code to add some random values to some random indexes of the series:

```
randx = np.array(list(set([randint(1, len(x)-1) for i in range(0, 2000)])))
randy = np.array(list(set([randint(1, len(y)-1) for i in range(0, 2000)])))

for i in randx:
    xn[i] = uniform(-15, 15)
for i in randy:
    yn[i] = uniform(-15, 15)
```

but this was not a good idea at all because of the 'x-y' scatter plot. the plot in this code is the picture below:
[image]
but the desired scatter plot is something like this:
[image] 
what is the best way to add some random spikes to random indexes of a signal to make a highly polluted series?

Comment: That's an odd requirement, because the X and Y error values are clearly not independent.  If they were, you'd see clusters at 25,15 and 25,-10 and -25,0 and 75,0.  It may be a little easier to think about how you would do this rotated 45 degrees.  Then the cluster probabilities are like 1, 3, 1 ... 3, 9, 3 ... 1, 3, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can give you some place to start.  It's not exactly the same distribution, but I think you can see which knobs to turn.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-75, -25, 25, 75, 125 ]
y = [-28, -14, 0, 14, 18 ]

distribution = np.array(
    [( -75, 0 ), ( 25, 28 ), ( 125, 0 ), ( 25, -28 ) ] +
    [( -25, -14 ), ( -25,  14 ), (  75, -14 ), (  75,  14 )] * 8 +
    [ (25, 0) ] * 64 )

# pick 10,000 points.

picks = np.random.randint( len(distribution), size=1000 )

# Split x and y

px = distribution[picks,0].astype(np.float64)
py = distribution[picks,1].astype(np.float64)

# Tweak the x and y randomly.

px += (np.random.random( size=px.shape ) * 5 - 2.5) ** 3
py += (np.random.random( size=py.shape ) * 3 - 1.5) ** 3

plt.scatter( px, py )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]